# AVPlayer can't play remote MP3 (iOS 8 beta 4)

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, ios8

I have checked through many solutions here, and it seems to boil down to these 2 ways of playing remote MP3:

Written in Swift (since all the answers are in Objective-C):

```
    let url = "http://megdadhashem.wapego.ru/files/56727/tubidy_mp3_e2afc5.mp3"
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL:NSURL(string:url))
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
    player.play()
```

or

```
    let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string:"http://megdadhashem.wapego.ru/files/56727/tubidy_mp3_e2afc5.mp3"))    
    let audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data:fileData, error:nil)       
    audioPlayer.play()
```

But neither seems to work. Am I missing anything?

Comment: `player` needs to be a *property* so that the player is not reallocated prematurely

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Play the file to convert in NSData.

```
 NSData  *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
 AVAudioPlayer *audio= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];
 self.player = audio;
 [[self player] play];
```

Comment: Isn't this the 2nd way I did it (I just did it in Swift)?

Comment: Does AVAudioPlayer work for streaming audio, tried this code but can't make it work yet.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having. AVAudioPlayer is only working when converting to NSData.

Comment: NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:streaming_path]];
            NSError *error;
            
            
      AVAudioPlayer      *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
            [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
             [audioPlayer play];
             [[self player] play];